# Why does my Linux text file (created with echo) end with a newline? How can I remove it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I'm facing an issue with adding a new line with sed.

I want to add a line into the end of the text file, I tried with

```
echo "Hello, how are you?" >> myfile.txt
```

But the issue is it's creating one more empty line like below:

```
 1 Hello, how are you?
 2
```

So I want it to create ine line at the end of the text file line; if there is no line into the text file then it should create as a first line without any empty/blank line.

Comment: Put another way, it is *correctly* creating a one-line text file where every line is terminated by a newline character. You appear to be coming from a Window background, where the last line of a text file doesn't need to be (and commonly isn't?) terminated.

Comment: Where are you using `sed`?

Comment: Arguably, it's your editor that's wrong for showing a line there.

Comment: Why did someone upvote this question? An upvote indicates it is useful and well researched. The best I can tell the question does not meet either criteria. How does this question meet the criteria?

Answer (score 3):

By default, "echo" adds trailing new line character. Use "-n" with echo to suppress the new line

```
echo -n "Hello, how are you?" >> myfile.txt
```

Another option is - using `printf`

```
printf "Hello,how are you?" >> myfile.txt
```

Comment: `echo -n` isn't specified (to do have any particular behavior) by POSIX. Much safer to use `printf` instead. See [the POSIX standard for the `echo` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), especially the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: That is: `printf '%s' "Hello, how are you?"` -- though the result isn't a valid UNIX text file (`while read` will return an error for the last line, f/e, since that line isn't valid without a newline terminator).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thanks for bringing to the notice. updated accordingly. :)

Comment: The problem with `printf "your string here"` instead of `printf '%s' "your string here"` is that in the former case, the content is treated as a format string rather than a literal, so you need to be careful of `%` signs or backslashes within it; in the latter case, what gets printed is byte-for-byte exactly what's in the argument.

Comment: thanks for your replay when I used echo -n "Hello, how are you?" >> myfile.txt its add line without extra line but then if I used again echo -n "I am fine, how are you?" its insert in the same line, not end of the line Hello, 1 how are you?I am fine, how are you? but I was wanted to add each line end of the file line without create new line, hope I make my question clear,

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.

Comment: @jww  what is your problem? if someone wants to answer or not its there problem, not yours, I think you are upset about something & you are getting out your angriness on this question/topic, Please deal with your own business, Thanks...